# How do I conditionally find mode in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, mode

I have some sample data in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database like following:

```
 Group      length
 A          19.3
 A          19.3
 A          20.3
 A          20.3
 A          19.3
 A          19.3
 B          22.1
 B          19.3
 B          
 B          15.5
 B          12.8
 B          14.7
```

For each group, I would like to conditionally find mode (the most repetitive/common value) using PostgreSQL `mode()` function such it that:

- If there is null in lengths, replace it with 0.0
- Find mode for each/unique group
- If there are two modes, return the biggest value
- If mode doesn't exists then return 0.0 for that group

The desired output could be like:

```
Group    length
A        19.3
B        0.0
```

How do I conditionally find mode, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think your conditions all boil down to:

```
select group,
       mode() within group (order by coalesce(length, 0.0) desc)
from t
group by group
```

If you have a row for `group`, then `mode()` cannot return `NULL`,so a further outer `COALESCE()` is  not needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot but it returned 22.1  for group B where there is no repeated value (no mode) and it should return zero according to my condition.

Comment: Why are you sorting by DESC? I added this line, mode() within group (order by coalesce(length, 0)) and it worked.